# job submission issues with the Slurm Workload Manager

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I am using a computer cluster with 20 nodes and each node has 16 CPU. I tried to submit 1000 jobs to all nodes with the command "sbatch XX.sbatch". What I want is that 320 jobs are running simultaneously, i.e.,  16 jobs per node, or 1 job per CPU.

When I use the . sbatch file with the parameters in the XX sbatch file is

```
#!/bin/bash
# Interpreter declaration
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH -J job_XX

./example.sh
```

I noticed only 1 job is running on each node.

Then I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
# Interpreter declaration
#SBATCH -N 20
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH -J job_XX

./example.sh
```

I noticed only 1 job is running in 20 nodes, i.e., 1 job per 20 nodes.

Then I tried

```
#!/bin/bash
# Interpreter declaration
#SBATCH -N 20
#SBATCH -n 320
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=16
#SBATCH -J job_XX

./example.sh
```

Still, 1 job is using all 20 nodes.

Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want more than one job, you need to submit more than one job. If you only call `sbatch XX.sbatch` once, only one job will be created (not quite correct, see below).

If you want to create 1000 jobs, you could simply go ahead and create a for loop to submit 1000 jobs:

```
for i in {1..1000}
    do sbatch XX.sbatch
done
```

This would create 1000 Jobs with 1 core each (if we take your first jobscript as an example) and they would fill up all available 320 job slots.
**But:** Calling sbatch in a for loop like that is not nice for the scheduler. There is a better way to submit a number of similar jobs: **Job Arrays**.

These submit a single job script any number of times at once. Inside the job script, you can then use environment variables such as `$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` to control your scripts so they all do exactly the same.

Take your first jobscript for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Interpreter declaration
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH -J job_XX
#SBATCH --array=0-1000

#Do something with the env vars e.g. use them as parameters for your script
./example.sh $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
```

When submitting this with `sbatch XX.sbatch`, this creates 1000 jobs at once, each using a single core, therefore filling up all 320 cores available.